# How to clear existing content before redrawing QGraphicsItem?

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a drawing that is built inside a QGraphicsScene with several layers of QGraphicsItem derived objects.

I am repositioning the QGraphicsItem objects based on some parameters and have noticed that there are some "ghost" trails left unless I call graphicsArea->viewport()->update(). I am repositioning the QGraphicsItem objects quite frequently (i.e. when a slider is moved) and updating the viewport only works if I call it manually some time after drawing is finished (e.g. on a button click).

One possible solution that I found was to fill the background of each QGraphicsItem to be a neutral colour. This doesn't work when I have overlapping items though, as the underlying items can get overwritten.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Sounds like it might be an issue with the graphics item's boundingRect(). Are they getting set appropriately?

Comment: The problem may be due to the boundingRect or shape functions, but as you're moving the slider, that could be a problem too. Can you add relevant code to your question?

Comment: It is difficult to post any code examples as it is such a big component. However, after I posted this I found that calling update on the associated QWidget as the first task in the paint function stops it from happening... I'll check the boundingRect too.

Comment: I should add that you need to be careful about calling update in the way that I did unless you limit it to avoid an infinite loop of paint-update-paint...